# How to avoid stackoverflow at collatz for high values?

Tags: java, recursion, collatz

I'm working on an eulers problem, where you have to get the longest collatz chain. The problem is, you have to find it in a sequence from 1 to 1 000 000. My code works great up to 100 000, then it throws `StackOverFlowError`. Can I avoid it, or is my code crap?

```
public class Collatz {
    private static final ArrayList<Integer> previous = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++){
            collatzLength(i, 1);
        }
        Integer i = Collections.max(previous);
        System.out.println(i);

    }

    public static void collatzLength(int n, int count){

        if (n == 1){
            previous.add(count);
        } else if (n%2 == 0){
             collatzLength(n/2, count+1);

        } else {
            collatzLength(3*n+1, count+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eliminate recursion, or make the stack bigger.

Comment: Or, use a stack object instead of a virtual memory stack

Comment: Do not make your stack bigger. Eliminate recursion. Making the stack bigger is only fighting the symptoms of your bad code.

Comment: But the iterative version will take 1 year to calculate?

Comment: If you want to keep with the recursive method, use memoization to store the results of previous calculations, that will speed up the algorithm and lower the number of methods in the stack.

Comment: @RokDolinar: What made you think that?  You're not doing anything in the recursive version that would be different or perform differently in the iterative version.

Comment: Alright nvm, I did the iterative version, but it "lags" at 113382. Why?

Comment: OHHHHH size of int is not sufficient

Comment: Recursion is normally not faster than iterative approaches. Most of the time you can find a much less memory and cpu intensive iterative solution.